# Calculation of Maxwell-Juttner distribution integral

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, statistical-mechanics

I am reading one very good notes on Maxwell-Juttner distribution, but I met some places that puzzled me a lot. Please give me a hand!

---

**The notes:**

Let $\Theta = kT/mc^2$ be the dimensionless temperature, $\vec\beta = \vec{v}/c$ is the dimensionless particle velocity, $\gamma = (1-\beta^2)^{-1/2}$ is the particle Lorentz factor (energy), and $\vec{u} = \gamma\vec\beta$ is the particle 4-velocity (momentum). The Maxwell-Juttner distribution is given by the following equivalent forms:

\begin{eqnarray}
f_1(\gamma)\,{\rm d}\gamma &=& \frac{\gamma u\,{\rm d}\gamma}{\Theta\,K_2(1/\Theta)}\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)
\\
f_2(u)\,{\rm d}u &=& \frac{u^2\,{\rm d}u}{\Theta\,K_2(1/\Theta)}\exp\left(-\frac{\sqrt{u^2+1}}{\Theta}\right)
\\
f_3(\vec{u})\,{\rm d}^3u &=& \frac{{\rm d}^3u}{4\pi\Theta\,K_2(1/\Theta)}\exp\left(-\frac{\sqrt{\vec{u}^2+1}}{\Theta}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

We make use of two modified Bessel functions of the second kind in the following integral form:

\begin{eqnarray}
K_n(1/\Theta) &=& \frac{\sqrt\pi}{(n-1/2)!(2\Theta)^n}\int_1^\infty u^{(2n-1)}\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\;{\rm d}\gamma\,,
\\
K_1(1/\Theta) &=& \frac{1}{\Theta}\int_1^\infty u\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\;{\rm d}\gamma\,,
\\
K_2(1/\Theta) &=& \frac{1}{3\Theta^2}\int_1^\infty u^3\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\;{\rm d}\gamma = \frac{1}{\Theta}\int_1^\infty \gamma u\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\;{\rm d}\gamma\,.
\end{eqnarray}

Normalization of the distribution is:

\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty f_1(\gamma)\,{\rm d}\gamma = \frac{1}{\Theta\,K_2(1/\Theta)}\int_1^\infty \gamma u\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\,{\rm d}\gamma = 1
\end{equation}

The mean particle energy is ([one can also check this numerical solution](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410370/268511)):

\begin{equation}
\left<\gamma\right> = \frac{1}{\Theta\,K_2(1/\Theta)}\int_1^\infty\gamma^2 u\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\,{\rm d}\gamma = 3\Theta + h(\Theta)\,,
\end{equation}

where $h(\Theta) = K_1(1/\Theta)/K_2(1/\Theta)$ is a function plotted below.

---

**Question 1:** What I don't understand are these two places, maybe they are the same problems:

1. how can we know:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{3\Theta^2}\int_1^\infty u^3\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\;{\rm d}\gamma = \frac{1}{\Theta}\int_1^\infty \gamma u\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\;{\rm d}\gamma\,.
\end{equation}

**Answer:**

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{1}{3\Theta^2}\int_1^\infty u^3\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\;{\rm d}\gamma
= -\frac{1}{3\Theta}\int_1^\infty u^3\;{\rm d}\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)
\\
&& =  -\frac{1}{3\Theta}u^3\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\Big|_0^\infty
-\frac{1}{3\Theta}\int_1^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\;{\rm d}u^3
\\
&&= \frac{1}{\Theta}\int_1^\infty \gamma u\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\;{\rm d}\gamma\,.
\end{eqnarray}

The first term vanish since $u(0)=0$ and $\exp(-\infty)=0$.
The second term, ${\rm d}u = {\rm d}(\gamma^2-1)^{1/2} = \gamma/u{\rm d}\gamma$.

**Question 2:**

2. how is this derived

\begin{equation}
\left<\gamma\right> = \frac{1}{\Theta\,K_2(1/\Theta)}\int_1^\infty\gamma^2 u\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\,{\rm d}\gamma = 3\Theta + h(\Theta)\,,
\end{equation}

**Answer**

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{1}{\Theta\,K_2(1/\Theta)}\int_1^\infty\gamma^2 u\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)\,{\rm d}\gamma
\\
&&= \frac{1}{\Theta\,K_2(1/\Theta)}\int_1^\infty\gamma^2u(-\Theta)\,{\rm d}\exp{-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}}
\\
&& = \gamma^2u(-\Theta)\,{\rm d}\exp{-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}}\Big|_1^\infty + \frac{1}{\Theta\,K_2(1/\Theta)}\int_1^\infty\exp{-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}}\,{\rm d}\gamma^2u
\end{eqnarray}

The first term vanishes, and ${\rm d}\gamma^2u= {\rm d}(u^3-u) = 3u\gamma\,{\rm d}\gamma-{\rm d}u$.

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{1}{\Theta\,K_2(1/\Theta)}\int_1^\infty\exp{\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)}\,{\rm d}\gamma^2u 
\\
&&= 
\frac{3}{K_2(1/\Theta)}\int_1^\infty u\gamma\exp{\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)}\,{\rm d}\gamma
+
\frac{1}{K_2(1/\Theta)}\int_1……\infty\exp{\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)}\,{\rm d}u
\\
&&= 3\Theta + \frac{1}{K_2(1/\Theta)}\left[\exp{\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)}u\Big|_1^\infty -\int_1^\infty u\,{\rm d}\exp{\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\Theta}\right)}\right]
\\
&&= 3\Theta +h(\Theta)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Look up integration by parts.  Note that when $\gamma = 1$ that implies that $\beta = 0$ so that's why the first term vanishes.  I think your limits are incorrect there, it should still be from 1 to infinity (i.e., $\gamma$ cannot be zero).  Hint for the integration by parts:  $u^{2} du = u \gamma d\gamma$.  You want to keep everything in terms of integration over $\gamma$ I believe.

Comment: @honeste_vivere thank you! I correct the typo as you pointed out.