# Energy and pressure relationship for cosmic rays

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure, cosmic-rays

How to prove $E = 3P$ for cosmic rays? In other words $\gamma = \tfrac43$ for cosmic rays. Whereas for $\gamma=\tfrac53$ we have $E = \tfrac32 P$.

Comment: Please define the terms you are using and describe the equations and context. Right now without specialized knowledge it's very difficult to tell what you are asking

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in the denominator is usually linked to diferent power laws in the one-particle Hamiltonian of non-interacting systems (e.g. classic ideal-gas: $H_i=\frac{\vec{p}^2_i}{2m}$, ultrarelativistic gas: $H_i=|\vec{p_i}|c$).

[This discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/376606) can be of interest.